# ASP Counters - difference between similarly named counters in different counter 'buckets'

Tags: asp.net, .net, perfmon

Best way to ask this question is by way of example..

Take counters

> \ASP.NET\Request Execution Time & \ASP.NET\Request Wait Time

There are counters with the same name in the ASP.NET Applications bucket

> \ASP.NET Applications\Request Execution Time & \ASP.NET
>   Applications\Request Wait Time

Anyone know the difference between the two? Is there a difference? Is one a subset/superset of the other?

Thanks.

Comment: Now if this had been related to jquery - I'd be damn sure I'd have got about 100 answers & comments at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET counter are global counters where as ASP.NET Application exposes per-application counters.
there is a special **Total** application instance in Performance Monitor that aggregates the counter values for all applications on a server.

Reference - MSDN

Comment: Thats what I thought, however looking a log from a production server running only one ASP.NET application (with web services only) and the values of these 2 counters were different: I seems to me that the ASP.NET counter always give lower values than ASP.NET Applications. Besides these two counter I also have two more counters: ASP.NET v4.0.30319 and ASP.NET Apps v4.0.30319. These last two counter seems to be versions of the above counters specific for .NET 4.X and, in this case, always show the same value of the version independent counter.